# inteceptor cannot use in Dio?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-plugin

[image]

I follow the Doc, but get some error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be useful if you repeated the error you get, but I'll make a guess at what the problem is.

The text `dio.interceptor` is not inside any function, constructor or variable initializer. You can only have expressions in those places, not at the top-level of a library.

At the point where you write `dio.interceptor`, you need to write a variable or function declaration. There is no valid declaration starting with `dio.interceptor` because it cannot be a type, so the analyzer will tell you that the program isn't valid and, likely, that a type is expected.

Whatever you are trying to do, put it inside a function, perhaps even a `main` function if this is the main file of your program.

Comment: thanks, as you said, I put it in function, it works.